# Can I use a Node.js 'mirror' as fallback when JavaScript not supported?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, node.js

### The basic question

Is it possible to fallback to a server-side Node.js implementation of an existing client-side, JavaScript-heavy site. Specifically for users who don't have JavaScript (or perhaps, if the client's browser fails to meet certain performance requirements)?

I'm really after an architecture thats a literal interpretation of [slide 8 of this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/sylvinus/node-camp).

Rather than mustache/backbone forming data structures and creating views on the clientside, instead this would be done in Node and the the fully-formed HTML could be returned.

### Background

I have written an application that is built on a stack of jQuery, Underscore, Backbone and Mustache (making RESTful API calls to a web service for data).

This all works very well with JavaScript enabled in the browser, but I haven't yet written a server-side implementation as a fallback.

Of course I could essentially 're-write everything' in C#.NET/Python/Ruby/etc., but this seems like a very poor solution, when you consider the amount of duplication and added maintenance,  when there is a fully functional version of the application available in JavaScript.

Comment: The server and browser runtime environments are fundamentally different.  (Node, for example, typically works in terms of requests and responses...it doesn't even have a "window" object, as it has no window to speak of.  And it can't directly modify the browser's DOM objects...it can only spit out different HTML.)  You're not going to be able to run the same code in both, in most cases.

Comment: @cHao I note that there will be certain caveats - but still, 'tweaking/re-writing' certain elements of my program for the server-side variations would still be more preferable to an entire re-write in a different language?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what elements you'd like to move to the server side? I don't exactly understand what the server would take care of if JavaScript is disabled. Basically, the mere thing that's equivalent between a browser and Node.js is the language.

Comment: Sorry yes, node would be forming/rendering the application views server side and then return that as an HTML file. Mimicking what moustache.js does clientside with backbone

Comment: Interesting idea. I don’t know enough about node.js to know if that approach would work. One sticking point is that with your current set-up, I presume onclick events handle user interaction. Your node.js back-end would have to convert each of these to a different URL, and respond to those URLs with the right HTML.

Comment: I don't know of any examples out there, but I have done it very easily with YUI on NodeJS. I won't post an answer because I don't links to good information, but I can tell you it's not hard if you are consistent in your use of "window", "document", etc. There are  tools even for helping you with that like jsdom https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though this is probably something that we'll see more an more of as we go forward in the world of server-side JS.

I might have a play with writing something myself, however as commenter (on the OP) [juandopazo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188729/juandopazo) mentions, this is possible already with YUI3.

Douglas Crockford mentions exactly what I'm on about (and YUI's cabailities) in [this video on 'Serversideness'](http://ontwik.com/javascript/douglas-crockford-serversideness/) - see from 03:45.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. It is even easier using something like express.js: http://expressjs.com/

Express.js, for example, has a function called res.render() which will render a template for you (in a wide array of templating languages).

The functionality of your client side app will have to be rewritten to work without js (clearly). But you could even dynamically generate anchor tags and pass them in as variables to your templates on the server.

Example responding to whatever.com/test that renders the template index.jade with the title variable set to 'My Site':

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res){
    res.render('index.jade', { title: 'My Site' });
});
```

As for reusing your entire backbone app on the server, I would imagine it is possible using jsdom and rewriting a ton of code. It most likely more cost-effective to just rewrite your app in a different style using requests and templates.